# Unflatten a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, each value in the dictionary is a list with 0 or more elements representing parent: [children] relationships.

For example, 
`my_dict = {'435': ['188', '436', '439', '1038'], '188': ['198'], '436': ['86', '115', '437', '444', '626', '650'], '439': [], '1038': ['733', '1037'], '198': [], '86': [], '115': [], '437': [], '444': [], '626': [], '650': [], '733': ['14'], '1037': [], '14': []}`

So, parent (and root node) `435` has children `188, 426, 439, 1038`. Node `188` has child `198`, etc.

I'd like to unflatten this dictionary (ultimately I would like the dictionary to be in d3 format needed for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) (specifically, flare.json))

Desired syntax, `[{"name": "435", "children": [{"name": "188", "children": [{"name": "198"}]}]}]`

I was thinking something like this,

```
my_dict = {'435': ['188', '436', '439', '1038'], '188': ['198'], '436': ['86', '115', '437', '444', '626', '650'], '439': [], '1038': ['733', '1037'], '198': [], '86': [], '115': [], '437': [], '444': [], '626': [], '650': [], '733': ['14'], '1037': [], '14': []}

for key, value in list(my_dict.items()):
    if value != []:
        n = 0
        children = value
        for child in children:
            children[n] = {"name": child} 
            n = n + 1
```

Or perhaps a recursive function would be better? I am unsure how to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with loop. Is it what you want following?

```py
my_dict = {'435': ['188', '436', '439', '1038'], '188': ['198'], '436': ['86', '115', '437', '444', '626', '650'], '439': [], '1038': ['733', '1037'], '198': [], '86': [], '115': [], '437': [], '444': [], '626': [], '650': [], '733': ['14'], '1037': [], '14': []}

table = {}
roots = set(my_dict)
for name, children in my_dict.items():
    table.setdefault(name, {'name': name})
    if children:
        table[name]['children'] = [
            table.setdefault(child, {'name': child})
            for child in children
        ]
        roots -= set(children)
result = {k: v for k, v in table.items() if k in roots}
print(list(result.values()))
```

output:

```py
[{'name': '435', 'children': [{'name': '188', 'children': [{'name': '198'}]}, {'name': '436', 'children': [{'name': '86'}, {'name': '115'}, {'name': '437'}, {'name': '444'}, {'name': '626'}, {'name': '650'}]}, {'name': '439'}, {'name': '1038', 'children': [{'name': '733', 'children': [{'name': '14'}]}, {'name': '1037'}]}]}]
```

explanation:

- `table` holds all items(name and children data).
- If an item has `children`, register them to `table` by `dict.setdefault`.
- `roots` contains all items that doen't belong any other items.
- At last, filter only items which are in `roots`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
# Python code to demonstrate  
# converting multi-d list into 1d list 
# using chain.from_iterables 

# import chain 
from itertools import chain 

ini_list = {'435': ['188', '436', '439', '1038'], '188': ['198'], '436': ['86', '115', '437', '444', '626', '650'], '439': [], '1038': ['733', '1037'], '198': [], '86': [], '115': [], '437': [], '444': [], '626': [], '650': [], '733': ['14'], '1037': [], '14': []}

# printing initial list 
for key in ini_list:

   # converting 2d list into 1d 
   # using chain.from_iterables 
   flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(ini_list[key])) 

   # printing flatten_list 
   print ("final_result", str(flatten_list))
```

Extrapolated solution from here: [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-flatten-a-2d-list/) I'm sure this can be optimized further but this should work and essentially throw everything into a single list within each dict position print the result and then initialize with the next dict key-value.

Hope that helps. If so, please mark as answer. Thanks